# Get-WmiObject with and without -list: different objects?

Tags: windows-7, powershell-2.0

I am using PowerShell 2.0 and trying to get the possible methods from Win32_ShadowCopy.

Now, when I use `Get-WmiObject -list Win32_ShadowCopy | Get-Member` I get:

```
   TypeName: System.Management.ManagementClass#ROOT\cimv2\Win32_ShadowCopy

Name                MemberType    Definition
----                ----------    ----------
Name                AliasProperty Name = __Class
Create              Method        System.Management.ManagementBaseObject Cre...
...
```

But if I use `Get-WmiObject Win32_ShadowCopy | Get-Member` i get:

```
   TypeName: System.Management.ManagementObject#root\cimv2\Win32_ShadowCopy

Name                MemberType   Definition
----                ----------   ----------
Revert              Method       System.Management.ManagementBaseObject Reve...
Caption             Property     System.String Caption {get;set;}
...
```

Now I don't understand. Why do I get 2 seemingly different classes? I expect the same result with both commands. I can find what `-list` does in the documentation, but not what the default behavior is without the `-list` switch. Anyone care to clarify?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is from get-help about list.

-List []
    Specifies whether to retrieve and display the names of the WMI classes
    in the WMI repository namespace that is specified in the Namespace para
    meter. The Default Namespace registry entry in the  HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\
    SOFTWARE\Microsoft\WBEM\Scripting registry key is not used by this cmdl
    et to determine the default namespace. If you specify the List paramete
    r but not the Namespace parameter, the root\CIMV2 namespace is used by
    default.

```
Required?                    false
Position?                    named
Default value
Accept pipeline input?       false
Accept wildcard characters?  false
```

for your script

```
Get-WmiObject -list Win32_ShadowCopy
```

equals:

```
Get-WmiObject -list -class Win32_ShadowCopy
```

which means you're listing classes with name Win32_ShadowCopy.

And the

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_ShadowCopy
```

equals:

```
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_ShadowCopy
```

which returns the objects of the specified class.

Answer (score 1):

Get-WmiObject by default will return *instances* of the given class.
Get-WmiObject -List on the other hand will return class itself. Latter is mainly useful when wildcards are used (e.g. to list all classes in default - root\cimv2 namespace with Disk in name you can do `Get-WmiObject -Class *Disk* -List`).

Comment: Seems plausible, but how come the instances of a class can have different methods to the class itself? Check the TypeName: it is different. Why?

Comment: I would compare it to `$obj = New-Object Class; $obj.SomeMember` and `[Class]::OtherMember` - class has some (static) methods/ properties, that are different from methods/ properties of object of that class.

Comment: OK, I figured it out. Each WMI class or object has an unique path of the form:
`\\<computer>\<namespace>:<class>.<keyproperty>="<value>"`

where `<keyproperty>` is a property that uniquely identifies the instance.

WMI allows you to see the “instance path” for any object returned using Get-WmiObject through the `__PATH` property on that object.